# Difference between : and = operators in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and trying to understand when to use `"="` and when to use `":"`. It sounds a bit confusing to me.

Here are the few things which lead to my confusion :

```
button.setOnClickListener(object : OnClickListener{
    override fun onClick(view: View){
    doSomething() }
})
```

Here "object" is a variable which holds a *OnClickListner* instance if I'm not wrong.

Following the above example,

```
class Car(val make:String ,var  model : String){

fun start(noise : String = "Wroom Wroom"){
    println(noise)
 }
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

val carOne = Car("Toyota","Avalon")
var car2:Car("Telsa","S")
car3:Car("Benz","C")

}
```

at function start, `noise : String = "Wroom Wroom "` is valid, carOne is valid but **car2**  and **car3**  are not valid  which follows the pattern of variable `"noise"`!

Can someone please explain where I'm wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html and scroll down to 'Operators and Special Symbols'

Comment: Thank you for redirecting me to that page. According to the reference, ":"  is used for type declaration, hence can't be merged with initialization. So the correct usage of car2 would be , var car2: Car = Car("Benz","C").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing Object Expressions and Declarations with regular variable declarations with default values.

`:` refers to the type of an object *or* to the supertype. In the case of the keyword `object` though, it allows creating an anonymous class that *inherits* from a specific type. This is similar to the other inheritance syntax in kotlin, but more specific. See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html) for more information.

`=` in this case just sets a default value for a variable. Note that in your example you aren't using `=` in a function call, but instead in a function declaration.

Comment: Thank you for writing this. The operator ":" is used for type declaration, hence can't be merged with initialization. So the correct usage of car2 would be , var car2: Car = Car("Benz","C").

Answer (score 1):

> **"="** Assignment operator-it is used to specify default values for parameters.

---

> **":"** Colon: it separates a name from a type in declarations

---

Comment: differences between kotlin and java: https://www.androidauthority.com/kotlin-vs-java-783187/

Comment: Thank you. The operator ":"  is used for type declaration, hence can't be merged with initialization. So the correct usage of car2 would be , var car2: Car = Car("Benz","C").

Answer (score 1):

= is for assignment
: for defining the type

however when your are using it as parameter in a function

```
fun foo(noise : String = "Wroom Wroom ")
```

**noise** is your variable

**String** is your type (defined by **:**)

**= "Wroom Wroom "** is the default value

Comment: This is probably also why type specification, by convention, doesn't have a leading space; it avoids confusing the reader (`var a: Int` vs `object : T()`)